# Get properties of array from View to Controller in MVC?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc

This is my form to submit

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SigningAsync", "Signing", FormMethod.Post,
    new { onsubmit = "return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');"}))
    {
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group" style="margin-bottom:5px !important">
            <input type="submit"
                   id="btnConf"
                   name="Sign" value="Confirm"
                   class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right:2px" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" id="arr" name="arr" />
            </div>

        </div>
    }

<input type="checkbox" value="@masterData.DocNo" name="selected" class="inforID" id="@masterData.NewDocNo" plant="@masterData.Plant" flowno="@masterData.FlowNo"/>
```

When checkbox is checked and Confirm button is pressed, I put attribute from checkbox to input `arr`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnConf").click(function () {

        var selected = [];
        $.each($("input[name='selected']:checked"), function () {
            selected.push({
                DocNo: $(this).val(),
                NewDocNo: $(this).attr("id"),
                Plant: $(this).attr("plant"),
                FlowNo: $(this).attr("flowno")
            });
            document.getElementById("arr").value = JSON.stringify(selected);
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(selected));
    });
});
```

The input `arr` will like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" id="arr" name="arr" value="[
        {"DocNo":"100400020719-006","NewDocNo":"ABS-02072019","Plant":"VDNF","FlowNo":"FLW-000001"},
        {"DocNo":"100400020719-007","NewDocNo":"ABS-02072019","Plant":"VDNF","FlowNo":"FLW-000001"}
    ]">
</div>
```

And this is the Action

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SigningAsync([Bind(Include = "arr")] PurchaseRequestViewModel purchaseRequestViewModel, string Sign, string[] arr)
{
    bool result = false;
    if(arr != null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Sign))
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
              string test = a[i].NewDocNo;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't get the property of object in `arr`, I have tried `string test = a[i][NewDocNo];` or `string test = a[i]["NewDocNo"];`.
But it wasn't right. How can I get the properties of array in the Controller?

I have tried `console.log(selected[0].NewDocNo);` in Javascript and it's ok, but in the Controller, it wasn't right.

Comment: In `Action` method parameter just change from `string[] arr` to `string arr`. it should work.

Comment: I have changed `string[] arr` to `string arr` and tried `string test = arr[i].NewDocNo;` but I have an error  `Error CS1061 'char' does not contain a definition for 'NewDocNo' and no accessible extension method 'NewDocNo' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value that you have in your HTML will be treated as a string value as there are not multiple values passed to the controller. You are only passing a single value. You need to change the method signature and use `string arr` and have the value as a string. Then do the conversion on the server.

Also, instead of submitting a form manually, better to use Javascript and AJAX to submit the data. Then you can pass the value of `arr` in the request body as JSON. Then that will automatically be converted into an array.